# Failure to launch VB.net application on distributed machines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, invalidoperationexception

I'm not entirely sure what's going on with this. The application works absolutely fine on my machine, but when being launched on another machine, it crashes at launch. This is the error log of the .NET Runtime:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          2/5/2014 2:28:50 PM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      -
Description:
Application: (executable name)
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
at        Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.
DoApplicationModel()
at  Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.
Run(System.String[])
at (executable name)
.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-02-05T19:28:50.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>1557</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>-</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Application: (executable name) Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
at  Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.
DoApplicationModel()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.
Run(System.String[])
at (executable name)
.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])
</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Which then caused this:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          2/5/2014 2:28:52 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      -
Description:
Faulting application name: (executable name), version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x52f17e27
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb10c6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000812f
Faulting process id: 0x758
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf22a87f1bae09
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\(application dir)\(application dir)\      
(executable name)
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: be39c661-8e9b-11e3-bb31-0007e9a790e1
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Application Error" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>100</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-02-05T19:28:52.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>1558</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>-</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>(executable name)</Data>
<Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
<Data>52f17e27</Data>
<Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
<Data>6.1.7601.18229</Data>
<Data>51fb10c6</Data>
<Data>e0434352</Data>
<Data>0000812f</Data>
<Data>758</Data>
<Data>01cf22a87f1bae09</Data>
<Data>C:\Program Files\(application dir)\(application dir)\(executable name)</Data>
<Data>C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
<Data>be39c661-8e9b-11e3-bb31-0007e9a790e1</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

This was all done with Visual Studio 2010. Any ideas? It's been an issue plaguing this project for a while.

Comment: How are you installing your program on your distributed computers, are you sure you have all the dependency's transferred also?

Comment: @MarkHall I used the Advanced Installer (9.9) and imported the bin/debug folder to be the installing folder. The libraries for the SDK's used are present within the directory if that's what you were referring to as dependencies.

Comment: I have run into problems like this using OCX controls that relied on system dll's that were not present. In my case it was the MCI dll. I found it by attaching a debugger to the failed process.

Comment: @MarkHall I'm not sure if I fully understand. You attached a debugger to the failed process? Which debugger was that and how did you go about doing that?

Comment: What I did at the time was download the .net ask and used the debugger that came with it. You could also try remote debugging with VS